# TCP Server to push data to a Web Browser

Tags: browser, webserver, tcpserver

I have a TCP server, which is connected to a web page via a Web browser. It is easy to send a request to the TCP server by the web page via the Web Browser, but is there a way that **TCP server can push data to the web browser, without waiting for a request from browser side??** My initial idea was that this is impossible, since a browser is stateless. But I was told there are ways to do that... Any ideas?

Thank You!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the experimental HTML 5 Websockets see [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/ffdead/the-html5-websocket-api) for the idea, or other [server push stuff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, <del>WebHooks</del> and [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) are the only ways to push data from the server to the client, while still using HTTP. See if they're what you're looking for :).

### Update

Try websockets (with [socket.io](http://socket.io), if that's available). Also, check out [meteor](http://meteor.com) for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

yes use the (network)stream to write data to the webserver